# What is the cokernel of the map $H^2\big(\pi_1(X), \mathbb Z\big) \longrightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb Z).$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology

For a manifold $X$ (for simplicity, assumed to be compact), let $\pi_1(X)$ be the fundamental group of $X$. What is the cokernel of the map $$H^2\big(\pi_1(X), \mathbb Z\big) \longrightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb Z).$$
The above map is as in [Interpretation of the monomorphism $H^2(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202976/interpretation-of-the-monomorphism-h2-pi-1x-mathbbz-rightarrow-h2x/207001?noredirect=1#comment513195_207001).

Answer (score 6):

Let $\tilde{X} $ be the universal covering of $X$. There is a Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence with $E^{pq}_2=H^p(\pi _1(X), H^q(\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z} ))$ converging to $H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Since $H^1(\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z} )=0$, the cokernel you are looking for is $E^{0,2}_{\infty}$, that is, the kernel of $d_3: H^2(\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z} )^{\pi _1(X)}\rightarrow H^3(\pi _1(X),\mathbb{Z})$. I am afraid there is no simpler expression.

Comment: $H_2(\overline{X}, \mathbb Z)=Hom(\pi_2(X),\mathbb Z)$. So we get a map $H^2(X,\mathbb Z) \to Hom(\pi_2(X),mathbb Z)$. Presumably this is the "obvious" map. Then you can describe this as the group of functions on spheres in $X$ that come from cohomology classes. I'm not sure if that's simpler.