# Identify the sphere bundle of a complex line bundle $BD_{2n}\to BU(1)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles

I'd like to know whether it is possible to identify the sphere bundle arising as follow:

Let $\xi \colon BD_{2n}\to BU(1)$ the complex line bundle corresponding to the element $y^2 \in H^2(D_{2n};\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z_2\langle x^2,y^2\rangle$ (we assume $n=0 \pmod{4}$ and $D_{2n}$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$).

Let $q\colon S(\xi) \to BD_{2n}$ be the sphere bundle of $\xi$. It's easy to see that it's a Eilenberg MacLane space $K(G,1)$ where $G$ sits in the following s.e.s. $$0 \to \Bbb Z \to G \to D_{2n} \to 0$$
which arises from the following piece of l.e.s. of a fibration 
$$0 \to \pi_2(\Bbb CP^{\infty}) \to \pi_1(S(\xi)) \xrightarrow{\pi_1(q)} \pi_1(BD_{2n}) \to 0$$
I'd like to identify such $G$. The Serre exact sequence in homology (integer coefficient) gives us the following exact sequence:
[image]

Since it's know that $H_2(BD_{2n})\cong \Bbb Z_2$, we have that $H_2(BU(1))\hookrightarrow H_1(S(\xi))$ which means that the exact sequence gives us $$0 \to \Bbb Z \to H_1(S(\xi)) \to \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2 \to 0$$

which implies that $H_1(S(\xi))$ cannot be a finite abelian group. In particular we already have that that $G \neq D_{\infty}$ since $H_1(D_{\infty})=ab(D_{\infty})=\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_2$.

From the exact sequence  retrieved by the dual Blakers Massey Theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880253/homotopy-fibration-and-exact-sequence-in-cohomology), in our case the base space is $1$-connected and the map is $1$-connected)

[image]

I was able to retrive this informations: $H^1(S(\xi);\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z$, the boundary map $\delta \colon H^1(S(\xi);\Bbb Z) \to H^2(\Bbb C P^{\infty})$ is multiplication by $2$ and $H^2(S(\xi);\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z_2$ since I know explicitly the map $H^2(BU(1))\to H^2(BD_{2n})$.

Is there a way to identify such $G$ completely?

Comment: What are your x and y? Is this the line bundle corresponding to the representation whose kernel is the subgroup of rotations? I think G will be the infinite dihedral group. The way I would try to show this is by writing the sphere bundle as $ED_{2n} \times_{D_{2n}} S^1$ and to realize this as $E(G/\mathbb{Z}) \times_{G/\mathbb{Z}} B\mathbb{Z}$ which is a model for BG. You just need to check that the two actions on S^1 match.

Comment: Dear James, $x$ and $y$ comes form the following $H^*(D_{2n};\Bbb Z_2)\cong \Bbb Z_2[ x,y,w]/\langle xy=x^2\rangle$ and $|x|=|y|=1, |w|=2$. Using Bockstein exact sequence then one has that the integral cohomology $H^1$ can be identified as claimed

Comment: Using hurewicz + the fact that mod $2$ homology is the dual of mod $2$ cohomology, one has that the dual of $x$ is represented by the rotation matrix and the dual of $y$ is represented by the reflection matrix.

Comment: Dear @JamesCameron maybe I'm missing something, but from the Serre exact sequence it's seems clear that $\Bbb Z$ injects into $H_1(G)$. If $G$ were the infinite dihedral group, then $H_1(G)=\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_2$

Comment: where is the fibration $BG \to BD_{2n} \to BS^1$ you are using in the serre exact sequence coming from? Something seems a bit weird since the classifying space of the infinite dihedral group is the total space of some S^1 bundle over BD_2n, maybe classified by a different map to BS^1, and your analysis seems to preclude this.

Comment: @JamesCameron The fibration I'm using in the serre exact sequence is $S(\xi)\to BD_{2n} \to BU(1)$. where the last map is the classifying map for $\xi$ and $S(\xi)$ should be the homotopy fibre of it.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll try to think about this some more today.

Comment: Too elementray to ask here, but is $D_{2n}$ Abelian? You seem to treat $BD_{2n}$ as $K(D_{2n},1)$ which has meaning if $D_{2n}$ is Abelian?

Comment: @user51223 no, in general (and in the case I'm interested) $D_{2n}$ is not abelian. I don't get your reasoning. If the topological group is endowed with the discrete topology, then $BG$ and $K(G,1)$ are the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is perhaps my problem with the notation. If $K(G,1)$ is meant, one may expect $K(G,2)$ with $K(G,1)=\Omega K(G,2)$. But, it is impossible to have $K(G,2)$ as this should have $pi_2=G$ where $\pi_2$ Abelian requires $G$ also Abelian.

The sphere bundle would be given by 
$$S(\xi)=\widetilde{E(\xi)}\times_{U(1)}S^1$$
I think. For a vector bundle $\xi:E\to B$ of complex dimension $n$ with a structure group $G=U(n)$, let $\widetilde{E}\to B$ be the associated principal $G$ bundle. Then the sphere bundle is $\widetilde{E}\times_G S^{2n-1}$. See a paper of Imaoka nd Knapp on sphere bundles!

Comment: @user51223 oh I see your point! I will look for such paper

Comment: you might want to have a look at the Gysin sequence in order to know more about the cohomology of such Sphere bundle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cohomology class in $H^2(D_{2n},\mathbb{Z})$ comes from a homomorphism $D_{2n} \to S^1$, which factors as $D_{2n} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to S^1$, where the map $D_{2n} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ sends the rotation to $0$ and the reflection to $1$.

So, you have maps $BD_{2n} \to B \mathbb{Z}/2 \to BS^1$, and you want to compute the homotopy fiber of this composition. To do this, first compute the homotopy fiber of the map $B \mathbb{Z}/2 \to BS^1$. This corresponds to the unique nontrivial central extention of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Now, you have a homotopy pullback diagram, where $G$ is the group you are trying to compute:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
BG   @>  >> 
B \mathbb{Z} \\
@VVV @VVV  \\
BD_{2n} @> >> B \mathbb{Z}/2 
\end{CD}
$$

Taking fundamental groups doesn't preserve pullbacks in general, but it does when everything in sight is the classifying space of a discrete group. So, $G$ is the fiber product $D_{2n} \times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} \mathbb{Z}$, where the map $D_{2n} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ is the one mentioned earlier.

Algebraically speaking, you have some central extension of $D_{2n}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, and it is pulled back from a known central extension of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, so you can use this to figure out what the extension is.

Comment: Is the map $\Bbb Z/2 \to \Bbb S^1$ you use in your factorisation, representing $Sq^1$ in some sense?

Comment: If you like you could think of the corresponding map $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty} \to \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ as representing $Sq^1(w_1)$.

Answer (score 5):

As is described in any standard group cohomology textbook, if $Q$ is a group and $A$ is an abelian group, then elements of $H^2(Q;A)$ correspond to central group extensions $A \rightarrow G \rightarrow Q$.

You are asking for a particular case of this.  As you have described your particular element of $H^2(D_{2n};\mathbb Z)$ by its image in $H^2(D_{2n};\mathbb Z/2)$, one might also wish to describe the extension $\mathbb Z/2 \rightarrow \bar G \rightarrow D_{2n}$, the quotient of $G$ by $2\mathbb Z$.

It should be easy to calculate the mod 2 cohomology of $\bar G$.  I have just be fooling with this when $n$ is a power of 2.  One learns that when $n=4$, $\bar G$ will be group no. 4 of order 16 as described on Simon King and David Green's remarkable group cohomology website http://users.minet.uni-jena.de/cohomology/.  When $n=8$, $\bar G$ will be group no. 12 of order 32.  I am guessing that when $n=2^k$, $\bar G$ will also be the extension associated to the canonical element in $H^2(D_{2^k}; H_2(D_{2^k};\mathbb Z/2))$, and is a 2-central group of rank 2. (2-central = all elements of order 2 are central.)

Comment: Whoops: that last sentence is not right when $k=2$: this would make $\bar G = (\mathbb Z/4)^2$.

Comment: Dear Nicholas, I'll meditate on this answer! it sounds promising though and I want the thank you for that

Comment: I was about to ask why my extension was a central one, but it seems it's the case: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48489/group-extensions-and-line-bundles-on-bg

Comment: your point of view is interesting, what relations can we draw between $G$ and $\overline{G}$? I mean, what can we say about $G$ if we know the mod 2 cohomology of $\overline{G}$?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to a **toy version** of your question.
Namely, I will identify $S(\xi)$ in the **special case**
when $\mathbf n = \infty$.

In this case, I claim that after suspending once, we have
$$
\Sigma S(\xi) \,\, \simeq\,\,  \Sigma (S^1 \times \Bbb RP^\infty)\, .
$$
Secondly,  I claim that there is a cofiber sequence
$$
S^1 \to S(\xi) \to S^1_+ \wedge \Bbb RP^\infty
$$
showing that the homomorphism
$$
H^\ast(S^1_+ \wedge \Bbb RP^\infty) \to H^\ast(S(\xi))
$$
is an isomorphism in degrees $\ge 3$. Furthermore, we can also show that the latter is injective in degrees $\le 3$.

**Corollary.** If $n = \infty$, then with any coefficients we have
$$
H^\ast(S(\xi)) \cong H^\ast(S^1) \oplus H^\ast(\Bbb RP^\infty) \oplus H^{\ast-1}(\Bbb RP^\infty) \, .
$$

Here is the argument.
In this instance $BD_{\infty} =   \Bbb RP^\infty  \vee \Bbb RP^\infty$ and the map $y^2: BD_{\infty} \to BU(1)$ is given by
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Bbb RP^\infty  \vee \Bbb RP^\infty @> (\ast,i) >> 
\Bbb C P^\infty 
\end{CD}
$$
where $i : \Bbb RP^\infty \to \Bbb CP^\infty$ is the evident map, and
$\ast :  \Bbb RP^\infty \to \Bbb CP^\infty$ is constant.

The homotopy fiber of this map$^\dagger$  (which gives $S(\xi)$ in this case) is given by the pushout of the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
S^1 @< \times 2 << S^1 \times \ast @>\subset >> S^1 \times \Bbb RP^\infty .
\end{CD}
$$
So there is a homotopy pushout
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} 
S^1 @>>> S^1 \times \Bbb RP^\infty \\
@V \times 2 VV @VVV \\
S^1 @>>> S(\xi)\, .
\end{CD}
$$
By taking quotients horizontally, the latter gives the desired cofiber sequence
$$
S^1 \to S(\xi) \to S^1_+ \wedge \Bbb RP^\infty \, .
$$

We can say a bit more:
the map $S^1\to S(\xi)$ is a retract
(this can be seen using the universal property of the pushout to construct the retraction). In follows that the map $S(\xi) \to S^1_+ \wedge \Bbb RP^\infty$ is injective on cohomology in all degrees. Furthermore, after suspending once, the cofiber sequence splits, so
$$
\Sigma S(\xi) \,\, \simeq\,\,  \Sigma( S^1 \vee S^1_+ \wedge  \Bbb RP^\infty ) \simeq \Sigma (S^1 \times \Bbb RP^\infty)
$$
where I've used the fact that $X\times Y$ splits as $X \vee Y \vee X\wedge Y$ after one suspension.

${}^\dagger$The homotopy fiber of a map of based spaces $(f,g): X \vee Y \to Z$
with $Z$ path connected is given by the homotopy pushout of the diagram $F_f \leftarrow \Omega Z \rightarrow F_g$, where $F_f$ is the homotopy fiber of $f$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer! I will meditate on this tomorrow, it's pretty late in my time zone now.

Comment: I have modified my post. I can only claim to give an answer to your question in the "toy case" when $n$ is infinite.

Comment: Dear John, I thank you again. Even thought it's a toy case, there is enough material for me to study. You never know if that might be useful in the future!

Comment: It seems that this toy case is in fact important, as there seems to be some relation about the group(s) $G$ when for $n=4k$, $k$ varies!

Comment: Dear @user51223 could you elaborate? I'm interested in that!

Comment: Since $D_\infty=\mathrm{colim}D_n$ as $n\to\infty$, then it seems that for various choices of $n\cong 0$ mod $4$, the sphere bundle of the associated bundles that you consider are related. Maybe $\mathbb{R} P^{4k}$ would appear somewhere or something like this. You basically look at the restriction of the bundle over $BD_\infty$ over $BD_{8k}$, and the sphere bundles must be related!!!

Comment: @user51223  What homomorphisms are you using from $D_n \to D_m$ when $m > n$?   What is your directed system? Note: There is a natural homomorphism $D_m \to D_n$ when $n$ is a divisor of $m$.

Comment: @JohnKlein I think of $D_n$ as a subgroup of the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$, and the maps that I consider are restriction of $\Sigma_n\to\Sigma_m$ for $n<m$, which I think are the same as you use when you consider $D_\infty$. Actually, as a side question, I then was wondering what is $BD_\infty\to B\Sigma_\infty$ in the light of Barratt-Kahn-Quillen ? Not sure, how much this is related to the present question?!

Comment: @user51223 are you sure that the embedding $\Sigma_n \subset \Sigma_{n+1}$ takes $D_n$ to $D_{n+1}$?

Comment: @JohnKlein Identifying $\Sigma_n$ with permutation matrices in say $O(n)$, it seems to that $\Sigma_n\to\Sigma_{n+1}$ given by $A\to A\oplus 1$ preserves $D_n$ in the sense that that image would be a matrix which leaves the $(n+1)$-th say vertex fixed ?! Am I taking something for granted which is not?!

Comment: @user51223 , that doesn't work. $D_3$ is a group of order 6 contains the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_3$ which is generated by the cycle (1,2,3).  $D_4$ has order 8. If $D_3$ were a subgroup of $D_4$ then $\Bbb Z_3$ would be a subgroup of $D_4$ which would imply that 3 is a divisor of 8. No chance.

Comment: Then what you mean by $D_\infty$? Would this implicitly mean that there are maps $D_n\to D_\infty$?

Comment: @user51223 $D_\infty$ is the non-trivial semi-direct product $\Bbb Z\rtimes \Bbb Z_2$. This is analogous to $D_n$ being given by $\Bbb Z_n \rtimes \Bbb Z_2$ (which is the group of isometries of a regular $n$-gon). There is an evident homomorphism $D_\infty \to D_n$. There is no evident map the other way.